# wrapper.find with id in enzyme and jest doesn't find element

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to Jest and Enzyme testing, and I would like to know why the find function is not working with id.

//html from react, just the code where is the id increment

```html
<div className="App-body">
  <div className="changePage">
    <button className="Selections" onClick={this.decrementPage}>Previous</button>
    <p className="changePageNumber">{this.state.page}</p>
    <button className="Selections" id="increment" onClick={this.incrementPage}>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

//test

```js
it('next page', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Home />)
  const incrementPage = wrapper.find('#increment')
  incrementPage.simulate('click')
  const countState = wrapper.state().page
  expect(countState).toEqual(2)
})
```

```
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

```js
25 |   //const text = wrapper.find('p').text()
 26 |   const incrementPage = wrapper.find('#increment')
> 27|   incrementPage.simulate('click')
    |                 ^
```

Comment: When I have issues where find is not matching elements, I use something like console.log(wrapper.debug()) to see exactly what Enzyme has mounted and what it's working on. It may give you some clues. Perhaps add the output of that to your question if not.

Comment: other than console.log, webstorm and visual studio code let you debug the npm test to set breakpoints and check variable content, play in debug console with different find combinations,etc. Setting a proper debug environment may help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using `mount` instead of `shallow`. `shallow` does not render beyond the first level of elements. In your case, only the div with className 'App-Body' is rendered

Comment: I have the same issue, and thanks, now I know the difference between shalow and mount

Comment: the problem is that reads my if and I want to read my else, any idea?

Comment: Yeah I know, but if you have and if else in the return, how it should be done for select one or another?

Comment: Then that should form part of your test. If(condition_not_met) { // incrementPage should be undefined }