# Enzyme Button Simulate Not Triggering onPress function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Currently trying to test to see if a button 'onPress' has been called after it is clicked but I'm having some trouble. In my `fires onPress function when button is clicked` test case in `SignUp.test.js`it is able to find the button and all but when the click is simulated it says:

```
Sign Up Page › fires onPress function when button is clicked

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      28 |     // wrapper.find('#navigate').prop('onPress')();
      29 |     wrapper.find('#navigate').at(0).simulate('click');
    > 30 |     expect(onPress).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                     ^
      31 |   });
      32 | });
      33 |
```

Here is my code to help:

SignUp.js

```
const SignUp = ({ navigation }) => {
  const navigateOnPress = () => navigation.navigate('SignIn');

  return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <Text>SignUp</Text>
      <Button
        id="navigate"
        title="Press me"
        onPress={navigateOnPress}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

SignUp.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import SignUp from '../../../components/SignUp/SignUp';

describe('Sign Up Page', () => {
  function render(args) {
    const defaultProps = {
      navigation: {
        navigate: jest.fn(),
      },
    };

    const props = {
      ...defaultProps, ...args,
    };

    return shallow(<SignUp {...props} />);
  }
  it('renders the sign up page', () => {
    const wrapper = render();
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('fires onPress function when button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = render();
    const onPress = jest.fn();
    wrapper.find('#navigate').prop('onPress')();
    wrapper.find('#navigate').at(0).simulate('click');
    expect(onPress).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475342/wrapper-find-with-id-in-enzyme-and-jest-doesnt-find-element

possible duplicate.

Comment: @AdarshHegde I tried mounting but it did not solve my issue. I'm guessing it has something to do with the differences in `<Button />` between react and react-native (I'm using react-native).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by invoking onPress prop directly and seeing if the function passed into said prop was called.

```
  it('fires onPress function when button is clicked', () => {
    const navigateToNextPage = jest.fn();
    const props = {
      navigation: {
        navigate: navigateToNextPage,
      },
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<SignUp {...props} />);
    wrapper.find('#navigate').first().props().onPress();
    expect(navigateToNextPage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```